# Four partitions on Windows 7

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7, acer, aspire

I've just made a bootable usb on windows7, and now I want to replace my windows7 with Ubuntu. When I choose the option **replace windows 7 with Ubuntu**, I need to select a drive. Since I have only one drive in my desktop, I must use it. But on **my windows the drive is partitioned into a C  and D drive (both 500GB**). I put all my files on the D drive, so I can still use them in Ubuntu. My intention is to install Ubuntu on the c drive from windows, but when i click on advanced partitioning tool, I see that there are four partitions:

```
sda1(ntfs): 14.7 GB,
sda2(ntfs): 104.9 MB,
sda3(ntfs): 492.7 GB,
sda4(ntfs): 492.7 GB
```

My problem is that I don't really know what the first two partitions are, and which one is the c:/ drive from windows. I guess it is the third, but I must be sure because otherwise all my data is lost. What exactly do I have to do to just install Ubuntu on one partition and keep another partition with my files (the d in windows)? Also I don't really know on what type of filesystem Ubuntu has to be installed on(fat, ntfs, ext,..). The desktop that I'm working on is a Acer Aspire AX3900. Thanks (and sorry for my bad English).

Comment: While on live USB drive. Select TRY before install option. Go to dash search for Disks or Gparted >>Keep them Open. Now open file manager browse through ONE partition at a time , will be easy to identify. Now if you found your windows installation drive by mounting one disk at a time. BINGO !! you can check it in Disks >>  Whichever will be your C drive will be mounted. Get the SDX from there , and now you are ready for amazing Experience called Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the second answer in that "my laptop already has 4 primary partitions" question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the partitions go sda3 is most likely the drive that you want but there is no way to know for sure with the information you provided. You could run `df -h -T` to see the written data on each drive and the GB amount should tell you which drive is which.

As far as installing Ubuntu goes I would recommend using Ext4.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use a mobile PC?

These partitions could be a rescue partiton, maybe sda1. And the sda2 partiton might be the boot partition of Windows 7. I would check if this partitons are a rescue and boot partiton by checking its data or asking your PC manufacturer or seller.

If these partitions are the boot and rescue partiton you could delete sda1, sda2 and sda3 with using GParted and create a new partiton. But if you want to use swap-space don't forget to reserve some space and use it as swap.

Now you can install your Ubuntu with using the new partiton I think it would be sda1 and using the swap space, sda2. I would also hang in the sda4 partiton in your system but you have not to do so.

I hope I could help you a little bit, if not please reply to this answer

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first partition (sda1) is indeed a rescue partition named PQSERVICE wich Acer provides as a rescue partition. This partition is normally hidden. The second partition is like you said a boot partition named SYSTEM RESERVED. The third partition was the C disk from windows 7 and I deleted this one, and created a swap space and a ext4 partition. I kept the sda4 partition with al my data on. 

So now I have in ubuntu sda1, sda2, sda3 (wich is extended and contains sda5 as swap and sda6 as ext4), sda4 and an unallocated partition (100 MB).

Comment: I would like to delete sda2 and the unallocated partitions, because I these aren't really necessary anymore. Is it possible to combine these with the sda6 partition?

Comment: Yes you can with GParted, which you can run via Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB or install on Ubuntu. Try this [tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html)