# Which partition is windows?

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 beside Windows 7. At the point where it gave me the option to increase or decrease partition space, I couldn't figure out which side was the Windows partition and which was the Ubuntu partition. Can you help? Left or right is Windows?

I have 350 GB of disk space and only want to allocate 40 GB to Ubuntu.  However, I don't want to make a mistake and allocate the 40Gb to Windows instead.

Comment: Better to use Windows to shrink the Windows NTFS partition and reboot so it can run chkdsk. Then you can install into the unallocated. But many Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary partitions. If so you need to delete one of those. http://askubuntu.com/questions/154222/four-partitions-on-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

gparted, Ubuntu and Linux in general recognize Windows partitions and will show the formatting of the disc correctly as NTFS (or on older Windows as FAT). Linux systems use most times `ext` with a 2, 3 or 4 behind it. So all you need to do is check the formatting of the disc to identify what kind of OS is on what partition.

Example:

[image]

Here sda1, sda5, sda6, sda7 are Windows related partitions.

Windows on the other hand does not recognize Linux file systems so do your resizing in Ubuntu and you should be fine checking what partition is what.

Besides that: Windows still insists to be on the 1st partition of a disc so I assume it will be on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

**From [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest):**

> #### Allocate drive space
>
> Use the checkboxes to choose whether you’d like to Install Ubuntu
> alongside another operating system, delete your existing operating
> system and replace it with Ubuntu, or — if you’re an advanced user —
> choose the ’Something else’ option:
>
> [image: img]
>
> #### Begin the installation
>
> Depending on your previous selections, you can now verify that you
> have chosen the way in which you would like to install Ubuntu. The
> installation process will begin when you click the Install Now button.
>
> Ubuntu needs about 4.5 GB to install, so add a few extra GB to allow
> for your files.
>
> Not sure about this step? Windows users can [use the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer),
> which will install and uninstall Ubuntu in the same way as any other
> Windows application. It’s simpler and completely safe.
>
> [image: img]